# SAPUI5 get current filters of smart table into controller

Tags: javascript, sapui5, sap-fiori

is there a way to get the applied filters on smart table into a controller?

I need the filters to define another manual filter in my controller. The following approach does work:

```
var oTableData = this.getView().byId("table").getBinding("items");
var filtersData = oTableData.sFilterParams;
```

The output of the variable **filtersData** looks like this:

```
$filter=((KUNWE%20eq%20%27100051%27%20or%20KUNWE%20eq%20%27100021%27)%20and%20(VBELN%20eq%20%27131%27))
```

The problem I have with this approach is, that I need to convert it to a suitable format to define another filter in my controller like this:

```
var filters = new Filter({
                        filters: [
                         new sap.ui.model.Filter("KUNWE", "EQ", '100051'),
                        ]
                    ,
                    and: true
                });
```

Somebody any idea? Thank you very much guys.

Comment: `var filtersData = oTableData.aApplicationFilters;`

Comment: That's it. Thank you!